# Drupal6 - set popup window to a link

Tags: drupal-6

In Drupal6, we can use [**l**](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l) function to format a link, but how can we set it to a [**popup window**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus)?

Suppose the original code look like:

```
<?php echo l('product', 'product') ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a popup using window.open is not considered a good practice. You may try the lightbox module (http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) for a better way of showing a popup.

However, if you do want to open a popup using window.open, the following should work -

Create the link with an id

```
<?php echo l('product', 'product', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'product-link'))); ?>
```

Add JavaScript (you can add it to your theme's JS file) -

```
$(document).ready(<br />
function() {<br />
  $("#product-link").click(<br />
    function(e) {<br />
      openWindow(); // function for opening window<br />
      e.preventDefault(); // Stop link from opening new page<br />
    }
  );
}
);
```